# Getting a wrong date format when getting inbox messages on Android

Tags: date, android, format, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

I'm using the react native sdk for SFMC and I have some difficulties with getting the inbox messages from the Android platform. Somehow the date format is like: `Fri Sep 30 11:16:00 GMT+02:00 2022`

And I can't get that formatted to a date object as the year is at the end. I could work around this, but is this the expected format or am I doing something wrong here?

When I do the same thing through iOS, I get the format `2022-10-11T09:53:00+02:00` which is working fine.

Update as an answer to Bill Mote:
There's a bridge created in Android to get the messages in RN. When I directly log the messages there:

```
List<InboxMessage> messages = MarketingCloudSdk.getInstance().getInboxMessageManager().getMessages();
Log.i("aaaaaaa", String.valueOf(messages));
```

I get this output:

```
InboxMessage(id=MjMzOjExNDowOnhVN3pqay04cVUyVllORnZxelJ6Q3c, requestId=8ef34ec5-bc4f-4da9-9560-d16fab34730b, messageHash=U4lzMwif3Db1PYIJNML8RQAAAAAA, subject= Inboxing Nico, title=null, alert=null, sound=null, media=null, startDateUtc=Mon Aug 22 15:22:00 GMT+02:00 2022, endDateUtc=Tue Aug 22 15:22:00 GMT+02:00 2023, sendDateUtc=Fri Sep 30 11:16:00 GMT+02:00 2022, url=[some url], custom=null, customKeys=null, viewCount=0), InboxMessage(id=MjMzOjExNDowOjVjVGNsVl9EdzBhZWhwcU5mY1JFeEE, requestId=95dcc4e5-c35f-46c3-9e86-9a8d7dc444c4, messageHash=U4lzMwif3Db1PYIJNML8RQAAAAAA, subject= Inboxing Nico, title=null, alert=null, sound=null, media=null, startDateUtc=Mon Aug 22 15:22:00 GMT+02:00 2022, endDateUtc=Tue Aug 22 15:22:00 GMT+02:00 2023, sendDateUtc=Fri Sep 30 11:16:00 GMT+02:00 2022, url=[url], custom=null, customKeys=null, viewCount=0)
```

update: Added bridge

```
@ReactMethod
public void getMessages(Promise promise) {
    try {
        if (!MarketingCloudSdk.isReady()) {
            promise.resolve(Arguments.createArray());
        } else {
            List<InboxMessage> messages = MarketingCloudSdk.getInstance().getInboxMessageManager().getMessages();
            Log.i("messages", String.valueOf(messages));
            WritableArray messageList = SFMCDataManager.processMessageDataList(messages);
            promise.resolve(messageList);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        promise.reject(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The React Native plugin does not provide hooks for Inbox Messages, and {bad response removed}:

UPDATE:

You can format the date as needed in your bridge code. For example:

```kotlin
// snipped from a toJson() function for `InboxMessage`
if (startDateUtc != null) put("startDateUtc", startDateUtc.asDateString())
```

Where `asDateString()` is an extension function like this:

```kotlin
fun Date.asDateString(): String {
  return SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US).apply {
    timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
  }.format(this)
}
```

Comment: I'll add some more info in my post. Unfortunately this is not my own written code. Where could those modifications be made?

Comment: Ask the person that wrote your bridge. `getMessages` is not part of the supported bridge.

Comment: If that person was an option, I wouldn't be here...

``List<InboxMessage> messages = MarketingCloudSdk.getInstance().getInboxMessageManager().getMessages(); Log.i("aaaaaaa", String.valueOf(messages));``

This is in the bridge and gives me the same strange date format.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I can't tell if your "thanks for the help" is snarky or genuine, but how could I possible guess at what's wrong in the bridge code that you have not posted. I affirmed for you the way the SDK works, and I can assure you that the date is at is is shown in its raw format in the screenshot.

Comment: I'm not asking you to guess, I thought you might have ran into something similar before? I added raw log of the output of the SDK showing the different format in my original post. So I feel like it's not the bridge that's the problem, but I didn't accuse anyone or anything.

Comment: Post the relevant bridge code.

Comment: I've added the entire bridge now. It's not much more than there already was, but maybe I didn't post the code in there in a readable manner.

Comment: See my updated answer as I show you how to format the date.

Comment: Thanks a freaking lot for pointing me into the solution! I've been spending way to much time on this. Although I still don't understand why the format is not returning correctly in my situation, this finally makes our inbox messages working like it should.
Would it be nice to make a PR for the repo as well to get inbox and in-app messages?

Comment: Just to add to the discussion. I haven't looked at iOS as that was working OK, but looking at it now it seems there we have the same 'strange' format, but that was already formatted like your suggestion by the developer who wrote this in the first place.

Comment: InApp messages are already supported. You just have to implement the URL Handler.